# Integration google, yahoo calender in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-calendar-api, yahoo-api

I need to integrate google, yahoo calender in my rails app.

Is there any gem or plugin for that, gem/plugin should have very basic feature i.e. creating new events and editing existing event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Think,
https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client and this http://blog.baugues.com/google-calendar-api-oauth2-and-ruby-on-rails may prove useful to you.
And about yahoo, I'm afraid they dont have a gem. Even I am in search for that!!!